# Can't run script file in docker, no such file or directory

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM alpine

COPY setup.sh /setup.sh

CMD ["/setup.sh"]
```

My setup.sh is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "hello world"
```

Tried to run these commands:

```
docker build .
docker run --name test 61230f9f45ad
```

Error returned is this:

```
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I'm using Powershell on Windows 10 LTSB, docker version is `17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6`. Why?

Comment: Works for me on a Linux host, but it's `docker run`, not `docker start` (start doesn't even have the option `--name`).

Comment: oh yes I had a little lapsus, modified

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is probably the Windows-style line endings that break it. Here's what the file looks like when saved with Windows line endings, but read in Unix style:

```
#!/bin/sh^M
^M
echo "hello world"^M
```

When interpreting the shebang (#!), `exec` will see an extra carriage return (denoted `CR`, `\r`, `^M`) and fail to find `/bin/sh^M`:

```
$ exec ./setup.sh
bash: setup.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Save the file with Unix-style line endings. On Windows, decent text editors (Sublime Text, Notepad++, any IDE, etc.) should be able to do it. There is also a simple command-line tool called dos2unix, which does exactly what you'd expect it to.

Comment: Even on Linux you can have CRLF in a Dockerfile...

Comment: ug, crlf got me, but my error message was simply; /bin/sh: my_script.sh: not found

Answer (score 6):

The [Alpine image uses `busybox`](http://gliderlabs.viewdocs.io/docker-alpine/), and [there is no shell in busybox](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#commands) since it isn't really meant for humans.

For your information replace

```
CMD ["/setup.sh"]
```

by:

```
CMD /bin/busybox ls -al /bin
```

You get:

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 ash -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 base64 -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 bbconfig -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        805024 Dec 12 10:42 busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 cat -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 chgrp -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 chmod -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 chown -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 conspy -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 cp -> /bin/busybox

[... snip ...]

lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 tar -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 touch -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 true -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 umount -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 uname -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 usleep -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 watch -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Jan  9 19:37 zcat -> /bin/busybox
```

In addition, if you look at `/lib` the same way, you'll find that the usual libs aren't there since `busybox` uses `musl` instead of `glibc`.

Typically, whatever is done in your `setup.sh` should be done with `RUN` instructions in the Dockerfile anyway?

PS: Incidentally,

```
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

means that either the executable is not found or one of its required libraries is not found, which makes debugging the Dockerfile quite difficult.

Comment: Didn't mark as solution because it didn't directly solve this problem. This is good to know tough.

Comment: So i assume that the other answer solved the problem?

Comment: Yes it did solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

It should use a Unix-style line endings instead of Windows. This problem occurs for me as well on Windows 10.

You should run the following command before cloning the repository:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then clone the repository and proceed.

Answer (score 1):

try to put in CMD or Entrypoint `["/bin/sh","/setup.sh"]` (or `["/bin/ash","/setup.sh"]`) instead of just `["/setup.sh"]`. It works for me in busybox container

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/439355)